# Использование ЭЦП для автоматической отправки заявок

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Задача: написать скрипт на python для автоматического оформления заявок на сайте mos.ru
Через API не получится, так как, судя по документации, API этого сайта предоставляет только доступ к датасетам, отправить никакую информацию нельзя
Решили писать парсер с имитацией работы браузера
Проблема в том, что для отправки заявок требуется использовать ЭЦП, без нее нельзя
Для отправки заявок пользователь приложения должен выбирать одну из многих ЭЦП.
Насколько я смогла раобраться для работы с ЭЦП требуется установить определенный пакет ПО, после чего привязать ЭПЦ к ПК, вставив флешку с полученным файлом ЭЦП
Приложение будет работать на VDS и привязать к серверу все нужные подписи таким путем не получится
Можно хранить на сервере файлы с открытыми ключами, но для использования подписи просто файла недостаточно
Плюс нужно в имитируемом браузере парсера установить нужные расширения (это, думаю, возможно)
Как можно реализовать механизм привязки подписей к серверу?
И какие библиотеки подойдут для именно такого парсера, с необходимостью установки расширений в браузер?